# Adjusted R Square For Binomial

Tags: r, r-squared, logit

```
mtcars=data.frame(mtcars)
m=glm(vs~mpg+cyl+disp+hp+drat,family="binomial",data=mtcars)
m=glm(vs~wt,family="binomial",data=mtcars)
```

I seek to estimate pseudo-r-squared that is adjusted for number of predict values however I have not seen such a resource.

Is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 1):

You could manually calculate it as 1-(Residual Deviance/Null Deviance). Both deviances are in your model output.

Comment: this does not count for one model have much more covariates than the other